#  adding pan and zoom error

Tags: compiler-errors, processing

I'm trying to add pan and zoom to my application which has written in processing.js , here is my code :

```java
boolean surfaceTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
pointNum=event.getPointerCount();
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//User is pressing on finger
float x0=event.getX(0);
float y0=event.getY(0);
mode = false; //DRAG
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
x1=event.getX(0);x2=event.getX(1);
y1=event.getY(0);y2=event.getY(1);
float z4 = dist(x1,y1,x2,y2);
mode = true; // pinch
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
// User is released one of the fingers.

break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
if (mode = false){
x1=event.getX(0)-x0;
y1=event.getY(0)-y0;
}
if (mode = true){
x1=event.getX(0);x2=event.getX(1);
y1=event.getY(0);y2=event.getY(1);
float z3 = dist(x1,y1,x2,y2);
if ( z3 > z4 ){ 
zoom += 0.1;
}
else if ( z3 < z4){
zoom -= 0.1;  
}
}
break;
}
return super.surfaceTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I saved older positions in case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN for zoom and in case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN for pan . I need this older positions to compare the new distance with old distance in zoom for example

this is the errors :

```
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\DOCUME~1\T0P4568\LOCALS~1\Temp\android893850823480544580.pde\bin\classes
    [javac] C:\DOCUME~1\T0P4568\LOCALS~1\Temp\android893850823480544580.pde\src\changethispackage\beforesubmitting\tothemarket\sketch_may28a\sketch_may28a.java:118: variable x0 might not have been initialized
    [javac] x1=event.getX(0)-x0;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\DOCUME~1\T0P4568\LOCALS~1\Temp\android893850823480544580.pde\src\changethispackage\beforesubmitting\tothemarket\sketch_may28a\sketch_may28a.java:119: variable y0 might not have been initialized
    [javac] y1=event.getY(0)-y0;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\DOCUME~1\T0P4568\LOCALS~1\Temp\android893850823480544580.pde\src\changethispackage\beforesubmitting\tothemarket\sketch_may28a\sketch_may28a.java:125: variable z4 might not have been initialized
    [javac] if ( z3 > z4 ){
    [javac]           ^
    [javac] 3 errors
```

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you are clearly using processing.org, which compiles its code as java.

The solution is simple: pre-initialise `x0`, `y0` and `z4` to a default value, e.g. `0`.

This is only to placate the java compiler, which is not smart enough to understand that b the time they are read, they will have already been initialised.